# how to validate marks for multiple rows?

Tags: javascript, jsp

here for each row each student marks have to be entered

ID    -------- MID1 Marks    ---      MID2 Marks
79 --------    20         ------------    40
63 ---   ---- 35         ------------    27

ID---------------> student ID

MID1 marks---> 1st mid marks

MID2 marks---->2nd mid marks

validate for marks greater than 40, we have to enter less than 40 marks so, it is validating for 1 row only

here the code it is,

```
<html>


<script type="text/javascript">

function validate()
{
var m1=document.getElementById("m1").value;
if(m1>40)
{
alert("Marks cannot exceed 40");
document.getElementById("m1").value="";
document.getElementById("m1").focus();
return false;
}
else
    {
        return true;
    }
   }

   </script>

 <body>

 <td><input id="m1" type=text size=18 onchange="return validate()"> </td>

 </body>
 </html>
```

i require all the rows have to be validated while entering the marks.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try this

```
function validate(field)
{
    var m1=Number(field.value);
    if(m1>40)
    {
       alert("Marks cannot exceed 40");
       field.value="";
       field.focus();
       return false;
    }
    else
    {
       return true;
    }
}
```

and in html

```
<input id="m1" type="text" size="18" onchange="return validate(this)">
```

And Provide different ids to your each input. as same id for multiple controls are not valid html.

Answer (score 1):

just use "this" instead of document.getElementById("m1") inside validate function